# Android select one of 5000 options

Tags: android

A little bit of an odd request here. I am trying to make an App in which an User needs to select one of over 5000 options. The user should see their name and preferable be able to search through them by typing in the first letters. Also only these 5000+ options should possible to enter.

I have looked at Spinners and PreferenceFragments, but none of these do the job for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try implementing a RecyclerView inside a new Activity ? Let's say you have a button that says "Select Option". When the users clicks, a new activity will open, with a search bar ( an edit text ) and a RecyclerView which will retrieve in its adapter all the 5000 fields. When the user types something inside the search, the array of data displayed will update to contain only the data similar to what the user searched ( + notify the adapter that data has changed ) . If search is empty, all data shall be shown for user to scroll through.
Then, in the View's onBind, you define an on click that saves the selected option in sharedPref, or returns it to the other activity with onActivityResult etc.. Its up to your needs here..

For big chunks of data, this is the easiest way to display and let the user select what he needs from your list.

Comment: Also, if user needs to apply selected items at once I would store selected indexes in a `SparseBooleanArray`. I would probably use `CursorAdapter` for the items, and used a `LIKE` statement with argument from the `SearchVIew` when querying.

Comment: That seems like a good idea! I would have to sort the strings alphabetically and place them in an array. How would I make it only display similar stuff? Is there any better method than using contains() on every ellement?

Comment: Go ahead and do it with contains(), i think it will be the best fit for your case. There are other options with Java Regex or so, but the native Java functions like contains() startsWith() endsWith() and so on should provide a good approach for the search-functionality